# PradoFramework: Does TAccordion need to have THead and TForm?

Tags: php, frameworks, prado

I'm learning about Prado Framework. I don't know why my code won't run when it doesn't have TForm and THead. The tutorial on Prado framework site didn't say anything about it. When I delete THead the page shows an error. When I delete TForm I can't change between view1 view2 and view 3. 
Here is the code

```
<html>
<head><title>Welcome to PRADO</title></head>
<body>

<com:THead>
<com:TForm>
    <com:TAccordion ActiveViewID="View2">
    <com:TAccordionView ID="View1" Caption="View 1" >
        <h2>View 1</h2>
    </com:TAccordionView>

    <com:TAccordionView ID="View2" Caption="View 2">
        <h2>View 2</h2>
    </com:TAccordionView>

    <com:TAccordionView Caption="View 3">
        <h2>View 3</h2>
    </com:TAccordionView>
    </com:TAccordion>
</com:TForm>
</com:THead>


</body>
</html>
```

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

```
PRADO Framework controls work within the 

<Com: THead> 
</ com: THead> is required
<com: TForm>....
</ com: TForm>

[http://pradoframework.net][1]
[http://pradoframework.net/demos/quickstart/?    page=GettingStarted.HelloWorld][2]
```

http://prado.com.co/foro/

good luck

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the **THead** correctly, even if your code seems to work this way, the generated HTML is far from the W3C ;)

**THead** simply replaces the use of `<head>` in order to allow PradoFramework to inject code according to different situations, such as the theme of your application.

**TForm** replaces the use of `<form>` in order to allow Prado to manage PostBacks or even better Ajax CallBacks. That's why all Prado's controls (`<com:T* />`) must be located inside this **TForm** and itself inside `<body>`.

With Prado, there is only 1 **TForm** for the whole page.

This is the right way to implement **THead** and **TForm** with Prado.

```
<html>
<com:THead>
    <title>Welcome to PRADO</title>
    <!-- All the <metas> and other needs of <head> come here. -->
</com:THead>
<body>
<!-- I recommend that you never place HTML here (or Prado Controls) -->
<com:TForm>

    <com:TAccordion ActiveViewID="View2">
        <com:TAccordionView ID="View1" Caption="View 1" >
            <h2>View 1</h2>
        </com:TAccordionView>

        <com:TAccordionView ID="View2" Caption="View 2">
            <h2>View 2</h2>
        </com:TAccordionView>

        <com:TAccordionView Caption="View 3">
            <h2>View 3</h2>
        </com:TAccordionView>
    </com:TAccordion>


</com:TForm>    
<!-- Here some JS OR footer HTML but NO Prado Controls -->
</body>
</html>
```